# how to render react state inside pre tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
              <pre>
                {`
                    ${Object.keys(this.state.myObj).map((key, index) => (
                      this.state.myObj
                    ))}
                `}
              </pre>
```

how can I render this out to show the state object inside the `pre` tag? currently it is just showing `[object object]`

Comment: `<pre>{Object.keys(...)...}</pre>` (don't use template literals in JSX unless you know exactly what you're doing)

Comment: It's unclear why you're using `Object.keys`. Are you trying to display an object or its keys?

Comment: trying to display both..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no different than any other case when an object should be presented as a string. In case the purpose is to display an object, it can be:

```
  <pre>
    {JSON.stringify(this.state.myObj, null, 2)}
  </pre>
```

It will have all implications that `JSON.stringify` may have, i.e. circular references or class instances won't be handled.